# Unknown metric function: {'class_name': 'TruePositives', 'config': {'name': 'tp', 'dtype': 'float32', 'thresholds': None}}

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have my Keras metrics defined as

```
    METRICS = [
          krs.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
          krs.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
          krs.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
          krs.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
          krs.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
          krs.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
          krs.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
          krs.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
    ]
```

and I use in compile

```
Keras_model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = METRICS)
```

For saving model, I have to save in database, so I convert to base64 and save as a binary file and using joblib load I load back the model, when loading back

```
ValueError: Unknown metric function: {'class_name': 'TruePositives', 'config': {'name': 'tp', 'dtype': 'float32', 'thresholds': None}}
```

But if I use only accuracy, it works

```
Keras_model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

using python 3.7.4, keras 2.2.5, how should I fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried using only load_weights?

Comment: As I am saving in database, I am not saving using model.save or loading using load-model, model is stored as binary format, so I use joblib load.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the error that it's looking for something else;

```
ValueError: Unknown metric function: {'class_name': 'TruePositives', 'config': {'name': 'tp', 'dtype': 'float32', 'thresholds': None}}
```

IT seems it's looking for something named as "tp", so try this,

```
dependencies = {
     'tp': TruePositives,
     # ....
}
model = keras.models.load_model(model_file, custom_objects=dependencies)
```

[Ref](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10104#issuecomment-387203517)